# Can I aim guns separately?

Tags: world-of-warships

Sometimes in the heat of battle there is multiple ships I want to shoot at, Is it possible to train cannon 1 on enemy A and train cannon 2 on enemy B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no. You can't train your main armament on multiple targets at the same time. However the [suggestion](http://forum.worldofwarships.com/index.php?/topic/32281-option-independent-control-of-frontrear-turrets/) has popped up quite a few times in the WOWs forums.

You can however aim your secondary armament at a different target to your main by holding down the CTRL key and selecting a target. This is also the case for your anti aircraft guns (hold CTRL key and select air group).

Generally only BB's have such secondary armaments for ship to ship engagements and the range is only short so to take advantage of this you'll have to get up close and personal.

Note: the 'P' key will disable your secondary armament and AA guns this is useful if your trying to stay hidden.

Comment: BB? DD? CV? are those the ship classes?

Comment: That's correct.  BB = Battleship, CV = Cruiser and DD=Destroyer. You'll see them come up in game alot in the chat or in the forums.

Comment: Just a note CV should be Carrier, the letters are based on the ship number BB-63 is USS Missouri a battle ship, CV-9 USS Essex a carrier. Cruisers are a lot more complicated with CA, CL, CG, and a few more being used. In the context of the game most are CL's.